# Oracle SQL - left Join on 2 tables does not run

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Anybody have any idea why when I try to run this query it just runs forever and does not stop??

The queries within the 'With' clauses run fine on their own. It's just when I try joining them I can't get it to run properly??

```
--Process name and input
With ProcessIn as
(
select Data.Scan_time, equipment.equipment_desc, data.serial_number

from Data, equipment

where Data.equipment = equipment.equipm_barcode and data.quality_plan = 'N/A' and        data.error_code = 'N/A' 
)

--Total process defects
,ProcessDefect as
(
select Data.Scan_time, equipment.equipment_desc, data.serial_number

from Data, equipment

where Data.equipment = equipment.equipm_barcode and (data.quality_plan <> 'N/A' or     data.error_code <> 'N/A')
)

Select concat(to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'), to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'dd')) as "Date", ProcessIn.equipment_desc, count(ProcessIn.serial_number), count(ProcessDefect.serial_number)

from ProcessIn 
Left Join ProcessDefect
On concat(to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'),to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'dd')) = concat(to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'),to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'dd')) 
and ProcessIn.equipment_desc = ProcessDefect.equipment_desc

group by concat(to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'), to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'dd')), ProcessIn.equipment_desc
;
```

---

UPDATE 20110816
I've used some of the suggestions to refine my query with no success. Does anybody have any other suggestion? Also, anyways to check that my index is being used properly as I am new to creating/using them. I just used the Oracle interface to create an index based on serial_number and smalldate.

Thanks

```
With ProcessIn as
(
select data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, data.part_serial_number

from Data, MIP

where Data.equipment = MIP.equipment and data.quality_plan is null and data.error_code is null
)

,ProcessDefect as
(
select data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, data.part_serial_number

from Data, MIP

where Data.equipment = MIP.equipment and (data.quality_plan is not null or data.error_code is not null)
)

Select ProcessIn.smalldate, ProcessIn.mip_step_description, count(ProcessIn.part_serial_number),  count(ProcessDefect.part_serial_number)

from ProcessIn 
Left Join ProcessDefect
On ProcessIn.smalldate = ProcessDefect.smalldate
and ProcessIn.mip_step_description = ProcessDefect.mip_step_description

group by ProcessIn.smalldate, ProcessIn.mip_step_description
```

UPDATE 110820

So I've been making some progress but need help figuring one last thing. I changed the queries structure to look like this now

```
select data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, error_code.error_code_en, count(case when (error_code is null and quality_plan is null) then data.part_serial_number end) as "Input", count(case when error_code is not null then data.part_serial_number end) as "Defects"

from Data

left join MIP
On data.equipment = mip.equipment

left join error_code
on data.error_code = error_code.error_code_sn 

group by data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, error_code.error_code_en

order by data.smalldate, mip.mip_step_description, count(data.part_serial_number) desc
```

As you can see in the select statement, I'm using case statements within my count functions. This works fine. Data output looks like this

```
Date    MIP_Desc    Error_Code    Input    Defects
1/1/2011    MIP Z    (null)       100      0
1/1/2011    MIP Z    A            0        10
1/1/2011    MIP Z    B            0        15
```

I'd like to fill in the same input value in the input column throughout all the rows that have the same date and MIP.

Output should look like this

```
Date    MIP_Desc    Error_Code    Input    Defects
1/1/2011    MIP Z    (null)       100      0
1/1/2011    MIP Z    A            100      10
1/1/2011    MIP Z    B            100      15
```

Any tips?? Thanks again for the help

Comment: Please post the query plan. It's likely that the query is very expensive indeed or that a poor query plan was chosen.

Comment: The way you have structured your query, the table `equipment` is involved twice in the query and joined via the column `equipment_desc` column, which is unlikely to be indexed. Wouldn't it be possible to join via an indexed column, or even better, involve it only once?

Comment: Off topic, but you should stop using implied join syntax. It is a SQL Antipattern and very bad programming technique.

Comment: What are the PK's of the tables and what, if any, other indexes exist on them?

Comment: @Codo - I don't have a query plan. I am just trying to take 1 data table and present it in a different manner, hence why the subqueries use the same data table but different where statements.

Comment: @Dave Costa - I don't have any PK's. I only indexed the serial_number and smalldate columns using Oracle's GUI to create indexes. Any ideas on how I can create more PK's for the table and index them properly so that I may try and improve performance??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Oracle developer, but a huge red flag to me is the use of nested function invocations on both sides of your JOIN statement:

```
On concat(to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'),to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'dd')) =
    concat(to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'),to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'dd'))
```

In SQL Server, this is a pretty strong indicator that the optimizer is going to have trouble using indexes to perform the join operation.  If your subqueries yield large record sets, the JOIN could take a very, very long time to complete.

If you can modify the ON clause to not require function invocations (on both sides if possible, but at least on one) it will probably help performance quite a bit.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can compare the day and month from a date/time column without the nested functions??

Comment: You could at least simplify it to `TRUNC(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME) = TRUNC(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME)` unless you really want the year excluded from the comparison. That doesn't however enable to use of an index yet.

Comment: You could do the converion of the data in the CTE part, then the join might be better. In SQL Server I would do this (including the conversion) in temp tables that can then be indexed and then do the join but I don't know if that option is available in Oracle. Of course you could just store the data the way you need it, then you only have to do the conversion  once.

Comment: I am trying to do trunc(ProcessIn.scan_time) = trunc(ProcessDefect.scan_time) in the main part of the query but it's still taking a while. I want to try using the trunc() in the subqueries before the main query using trunc(data.scan_time) as "smalldate", but the main query won't recognize something like ProcessIn.smalldate or ProcessIn.trunc(data.scan_time). Any ideas on this??

Answer (score 1):

Another way to simplify this

concat(to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'),to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'dd')) = concat(to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'mm'),to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'dd'))

would be to say something like

to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm') = to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm').

To improve performance you could create function based indexes

create index scan_time_idx on ProcessIn(to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm'));

create index scan_time_idx on ProcessIn(to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm'));

See http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_function_based_index_2.html
for more information on function based indexes.

Alternatively you could store scan_time in a separate column called monthday on the 'data' table in the to_char(tablename.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm') format, and index the new column.

Once created, your query would then look like this :-

```
With ProcessIn as
(
select Data.Scan_time, equipment.equipment_desc, data.serial_number,Data.monthday

from Data, equipment

where Data.equipment = equipment.equipm_barcode and data.quality_plan = 'N/A'    and        data.error_code = 'N/A' 
)

--Total process defects
,ProcessDefect as
(
select Data.Scan_time, equipment.equipment_desc, data.serial_number,Data.monthday

from Data, equipment

where Data.equipment = equipment.equipm_barcode and (data.quality_plan <> 'N/A' or         data.error_code <> 'N/A')
)

Select monthday as "Date", ProcessIn.equipment_desc,                                     count(ProcessIn.serial_number),     count(ProcessDefect.serial_number)

from ProcessIn 
Left Join ProcessDefect
On ProcessIn.monthday = ProcessDefect.monthday
and ProcessIn.equipment_desc = ProcessDefect.equipment_desc
group by ProcessIn.monthday, ProcessIn.equipment_desc
;
```

Comment: Since `ProcessIn` and `ProcessDefect` are factored subqueries, not tables, you would actually want `create index scan_time_idx on Data (to_char(scan_time, 'ddmm'))`.  But I don't think that would be used to execute this query since the actual expression wouldn't match the indexed expression exactly.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice that @Dave costa, I agree it should be the table data that has the function based index on. Not sure why it wouldn't work though, as long as the join was changed to to_char(ProcessIn.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm') = to_char(ProcessDefect.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm')

Comment: I have tried your simple suggestion of adding a new column with to_char(tablename.SCAN_TIME, 'ddmm') as a test but unfortunately this doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: @AFJ did you populate the column with the new data, create an index on it, then change the join condition of your query to use the column,  as now illustrated in the answer ?

Comment: @stevo yes, those are the steps that I followed. Again, i'm not sure if i'm using the indexes properly as I'm just learning as I go.

I used Oracle's GUI to create a new index on the part_serial_number and smalldate columns and then ran (or attempted to run) the new query above

Comment: @AFJ Do you also have indexes on Data.equipment or equipment.equipm_barcode ? It would be helpful if you could post an explain plan of your query, this would give us an indication of what indexes your optimizer is trying to use. Also, what exactly do you mean by 'the oracle interface' ? Are you using sql developer, or toad, or similar ?

Comment: @stevo No, I do not have those indexes. I am using the Oracle SQL Developer software for Mac. In the program I can right-click a table, choose indexes, then create index. That's what I've been doing. 

I will go ahead and add those 2 indexes you asked about.

Comment: @AFJ According to [link]http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31695/intro.htm you should have a tab on your sql worksheet that says explain. Highlight your query, hit the explain plan button in the toolbar, then post whatever is returned in the explain tab in your question.

Comment: @stevo I got the explain plan.

If I try pasting it in here it looks very messy and unreadable. The highlight I think is that the total cost of the query is 61250891. Of that, the top cost is Hash Join with Right Outer takes 3504768 and its predicates are AND -> ProcessIn.smalldate = ProcessDefect.smalldate, ProcessIn.mip_step_description = ProcessDefect.mip_step_description

What is this cost measured in??

I do have indexes on both mip_step_description and smalldate

Comment: @afj Could you run this query SELECT quality_plan,error_code,COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY quality_plan,error_code and let us know what it returns ? Looks as though the optimizer thinks a hash join is the best way query back the data, the query might help us to see if we agree. You may need to  gather stats, see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/stats.htm for why.

Comment: @stevo thanks, I'll let you know what I get. BTW, do you have any ideas on the latest question I posted in my update above 110820??